# How to use .Net assembly in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have .Net assembly (dll file) that I have imported in Ms Sql server. I have read that MongoDB also supports .Net driver. Is there any way that I can import this assembly in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB use a [Wire Protocol](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/) that drivers implement to connect. In the case of .NET, there is a [C# and .NET MongoDB Driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/) you can use to develop .NET applications.

There is no concept of importing assembly files into MongoDB.